# Sharing excel file without giving access to queries in the excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

can we share a excel sheet which has Queries and connection to other people by not giving access to them like a protectecd worksheet which has formulas and macros

i have tried to delete the connections and to  share, i dint want to do this, but is there way of not givivg access to those

Answer (score 0):

You need copy/paste data as values. Then remove all connections. I don't know a way to protect connections.

Or you can publish the worksheet in the pdf format.

Or (last minute idea) you can connect through ODBC. Details of connection are stored in the connection file not in a workbook. It should prevent users to get connection details while the connection itself is evident.